# Prevent upload a video that exceeds the limit

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an app that can upload/ record a video. I set a limit to video but when I upload from library a video that exceeds the limit, a  pop-up appear "Video Too Long to Send", but I can choose the video. 
My issue is: can I disable choose button or make something to stop upload the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before uploading video you should check video size. I have done it with my swift application. I have used following code.

```
let data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: <video URL>)!
if !isFileSizeUpTo10Mebibytes(data.length)
{
//File is more than 10 MB.
}

func isFileSizeUpTo10Mebibytes(fileSize: Int) -> Bool {
    return fileSize <= 10485760
}
```

Comment: I'm using imagePickerController delegate. Any solutions with that?

Comment: In your didfinishpickingmediawithinfo method check video size -
if let videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
            let data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoUrl)!
            if !isFileSizeUpTo10Mebibytes(data.length)
            {
                //Video large than 10 MB
            }
}

Comment: If you are using Objective C, just copy this code in your didFinishPickingMediaInfo method - 
'NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
        if (data.length > 10485760) {
            //Video large than 10MB
        }'